# Magento 2 how to split payment?

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, order-splitting

I'm doing an e-commerce multivendor, so when a customer buys from the website I need to do an order split and payment split. The payment seems to be more problem, how can I automatically do this?

I was thinking in an observer before order placed or pluginBefore. But I have no idea of the module that does this.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that this is not a Magento default functionality.

So, you might need to integrate third party module.

Followings are the example for split and partial payment module.

1. [Layaway and Partial Payment](https://marketplace.magento.com/fme-layaway.html?gclid=CjwKCAjwq_D7BRADEiwAVMDdHr2NdGUFUM6LV80sch5jVjzyILn-_ZtMkSeKPp3V2KD5g9q7zm78bRoC37cQAvD_BwE)
2. [Split order on checkout page](https://marketplace.magento.com/sunarc-magento2-splitorderpro.html)

If this helps then hit **like**.

Enjoy your coding!!! :)

Thank you
Hiren Patel

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to find a way to code it.

Comment: Yes, create new sales_order attribute with name parent_order_id. then create new quote and order in which scenario you need and set parent_order_id = <original order id > .  that is how you can split your order and similarly you can do code for payment for each child order.